# What does an asterisk mean in analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Please help me to identify what the asterisk symbolizes in the following:

[image: Textbook sample]

I would have thought it would mean a dual space, but the author uses $'$ to symbolize the dual space. In fact, the preceding paragraph is this: [image] If it is the dual space, I do not understand how $l_q$ is the dual of $l_p$. The asterisk is not introduced earlier in the notes.

Comment: One is algebraic dual  and the other topological dual.

Comment: From the following exercises it seems like he uses $*$ to indicate the dual space in any case, e.g. in proving that $(V \times W)^*\cong V^*\times W^*$. Also, in proof of theorem 2.33 he says "Fix $F \in V'\setminus \{0\}$" but then he claims "Since $F \in V^*\setminus \{0\}$...".

Comment: see also here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asterisk.html

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I am sorry but I don't see anything relevant in the reference you have given. You should check first...

Answer (score 5):

The **algebraic dual** space of a vector space $V$ is the space of the linear functionals on $V$. If $V$ is finite dimensional than all linear functional are continuous but this is not true, in general, if  $V$ is infinite dimensional. So, in this case we introduce the notion of **continuous (or topological) dual** space, that is the subspace of the algebraic dual that contains all the continuous functional. It seems that in your case (note that the $l^p$ spaces are infinite dimensional) the algebraic dual is indicated by $V'$ and the topological dual by $V^*$.

The proof that the (topological) dual of $l^p$ is $l^q$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$ is classical and you can find it on any book on functional analysis. You can also see a sketch [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Properties_of_Lp_spaces).